# Elasticserach filter on aggregated results (SQL HAVING)

Tags: elasticsearch, count, aggregate, having

I have an ES query that aggregates data from a monitoring tool.

Currently, I've found the number of documents in each relevant group (by "externalId").

Now, I wish to filter the results by the number of records in each group.
(Similar to "HAVING" clause in SQL, doc_count > 0)

For instance, to find the "externalId" that stored more then one time.

**This is my ES query:**

```
{
"query":
{
   "match" :
    {
        "method" : "METHOD_NAME"
    }
},
"size":0,
"aggs":
{
  "group_by_external_id":
  {
    "terms":
    {
      "field": "externalId"
    }
  }
}
}
```

**The results looks like this:**

```
"aggregations": {
"group_by_external_id": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 5,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 53056,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "6088417651626873",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "6088417688232882",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms aggregations have a [`min_doc_count` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) you can use. For example,

```
"aggs":
{
  "group_by_external_id":
  {
    "terms":
    {
      "field": "externalId",
      "min_doc_count": 2
    }
  }
}
```